# ios7 mapview annotation button not showing

Tags: objective-c, ios7

been googling this one for a good bit and i'm totally at a loss.

i'm porting to ios7 an app i built with a mapview with basic system annotations. everything is working great, the annotations are handling taps and acting as they're supposed to - but for some reason, there's no disclosure button appearing in the annotation. i haven't changed anything for prior ios7 releases and all the searching i've done has given me very little.

i've looked through changelogs and googled everything i can possibly come up with to solve this problem, and nothing has even remotely helped.

for my annotation view (which presented the old typical blue arrow button previously) i simply have …

```
UIButton* rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
pinView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;
```

which looks right and should be right (again, it's fine in ios6 and before) be for some reason, any sort of representation of a button is just not appearing.

thanks for any help here.

Answer (score 1):

hahah oh jeez, this is why i shouldn't be working so late.

the default color of the disclosure button is apparently white. like the default annotation background color.

derp.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and hopefully this can help someone else looking here, I didn't seem to require this for the disclosure indicator to appear before iOS7, but I forgot to set the mapView delegate. Once I added this to the viewDidLoad, my indicators started to appear (even though the annotations were appearing without it):

```
    mapView.delegate = self;
```